# GWT error while launching Development mode on Jetty or external server

Tags: java, gwt

I'm receiving following GWT error . I have tried to use both on Jetty & External server launch (dev mode) both gives same error.

```
URL index.html normalized as http://127.0.0.1:8888/index.html
Linking modules
   Bootstrap link for command-line module 'com.avaya.ept.chrome'
      Linking module 'ANSWebPortal'
         Constructing StandardLinkerContext
         Invoking Linker RPC policy file manifest
         Invoking Linker Standard
            Attempting to optimize JS
com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.InternalCompilerException: Unexpected error during visit.
    at com.google.gwt.dev.js.ast.JsVisitor.translateException(JsVisitor.java:483)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.js.ast.JsVisitor.doTraverse(JsVisitor.java:470)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.js.ast.JsVisitor.doAccept(JsVisitor.java:445)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.js.ast.JsVisitor.accept(JsVisitor.java:109)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.js.JsToStringGenerationVisitor.visit(JsToStringGenerationVisitor.java:835)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.js.ast.JsVars$JsVar.traverse(JsVars.java:61)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.js.ast.JsVisitor.doTraverse(JsVisitor.java:468)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.js.ast.JsVisitor.doAccept(JsVisitor.java:445)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.js.ast.JsVisitor.accept(JsVisitor.java:109)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.js.JsToStringGenerationVisitor.visit(JsToStringGenerationVisitor.java:848)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.js.ast.JsVars.traverse(JsVars.java:101)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.js.ast.JsVisitor.doTraverse(JsVisitor.java:468)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.js.ast.JsVisitor.doAccept(JsVisitor.java:445)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.js.ast.JsVisitor.accept(JsVisitor.java:109)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.js.JsToStringGenerationVisitor.printJsBlock(JsToStringGenerationVisitor.java:907)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.js.JsSourceGenerationVisitor.visit(JsSourceGenerationVisitor.java:59)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.js.ast.JsBlock.traverse(JsBlock.java:47)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.js.ast.JsVisitor.doTraverse(JsVisitor.java:468)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.js.ast.JsVisitor.doAccept(JsVisitor.java:445)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.js.ast.JsVisitor.accept(JsVisitor.java:109)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.js.JsToStringGenerationVisitor.visit(JsToStringGenerationVisitor.java:497)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.js.ast.JsFunction.traverse(JsFunction.java:200)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.js.ast.JsVisitor.doTraverse(JsVisitor.java:468)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.js.ast.JsVisitor.doAccept(JsVisitor.java:445)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.js.ast.JsVisitor.accept(JsVisitor.java:109)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.js.JsToStringGenerationVisitor.visit(JsToStringGenerationVisitor.java:392)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.js.ast.JsExprStmt.traverse(JsExprStmt.java:41)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.js.ast.JsVisitor.doTraverse(JsVisitor.java:468)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.js.ast.JsVisitor.doAccept(JsVisitor.java:445)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.js.ast.JsVisitor.accept(JsVisitor.java:109)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.js.JsToStringGenerationVisitor.printJsBlock(JsToStringGenerationVisitor.java:907)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.js.JsSourceGenerationVisitor.visit(JsSourceGenerationVisitor.java:59)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.js.ast.JsBlock.traverse(JsBlock.java:47)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.js.ast.JsVisitor.doTraverse(JsVisitor.java:468)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.js.ast.JsVisitor.doAccept(JsVisitor.java:445)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.js.ast.JsVisitor.accept(JsVisitor.java:109)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.js.ast.JsProgramFragment.traverse(JsProgramFragment.java:41)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.js.ast.JsVisitor.doTraverse(JsVisitor.java:468)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.js.ast.JsVisitor.doAccept(JsVisitor.java:445)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.js.ast.JsVisitor.accept(JsVisitor.java:109)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.js.ast.JsProgram.traverse(JsProgram.java:140)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.js.ast.JsVisitor.doTraverse(JsVisitor.java:468)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.js.ast.JsVisitor.doAccept(JsVisitor.java:445)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.js.ast.JsVisitor.accept(JsVisitor.java:109)
    at com.google.gwt.core.ext.linker.impl.StandardLinkerContext.optimizeJavaScript(StandardLinkerContext.java:471)
    at com.google.gwt.core.ext.linker.impl.SelectionScriptLinker.generateSelectionScript(SelectionScriptLinker.java:433)
    at com.google.gwt.core.ext.linker.impl.SelectionScriptLinker.generateSelectionScript(SelectionScriptLinker.java:422)
    at com.google.gwt.core.ext.linker.impl.SelectionScriptLinker.emitSelectionScript(SelectionScriptLinker.java:309)
    at com.google.gwt.core.ext.linker.impl.SelectionScriptLinker.link(SelectionScriptLinker.java:210)
    at com.google.gwt.core.ext.linker.impl.StandardLinkerContext.invokeFinalLink(StandardLinkerContext.java:328)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.link(DevModeBase.java:1009)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.doSlowStartup(DevMode.java:409)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.startUp(DevModeBase.java:1130)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.run(DevModeBase.java:844)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.main(DevMode.java:322)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.gwt.util.tools.shared.StringUtils.javaScriptString(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;
    at com.google.gwt.dev.js.JsToStringGenerationVisitor.printStringLiteral(JsToStringGenerationVisitor.java:1287)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.js.JsToStringGenerationVisitor.visit(JsToStringGenerationVisitor.java:775)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.js.ast.JsStringLiteral.traverse(JsStringLiteral.java:62)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.js.ast.JsVisitor.doTraverse(JsVisitor.java:468)
    ... 53 more
Stopping Jetty server
   Destroying Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcher'
   Closing Spring root WebApplicationContext
```

The issue is new GWT . OLD GWT I dont find in googles site. Earlier I was using 2.2.

```
Currently MY GWT Kit is 2.7.1.

Please help..
```

Comment: That must be a classpath conflict; make sure you don't have a dependency bringing an older/modified version of that StringUtils class. Also, btw, there's no GWT 2.7.1  (2.6.1, 2.7.0, but no 2.7.1)

Answer (score 0):

You probably have a classpath error, or related. Please check the following:

- gwt-dev jar is present in your launcher's classpath (if you're using Eclipse, then it is possible to customize the GWT launch configuration, and edit its classpath)
- you have only one instance of gwt-dev and gwt-user in your classpath (and not multiple versions, etc)
- make sure you're not including Jetty's jars through other means (case in which there might be a conflict with Jetty classes brought through gwt-dev)
- make sure you don't have multiple validation-api/hibernate validators (highly unlikely that this might cause this kind of problem, but still possible).

Comment: I have only one gwt-dev jar & one gwt-user in my classpath.

Comment: If you're using Maven, can you perhaps post your mvn dependency:tree output (or similar for your build tool). Although less likely, the other points in my answer CAN cause this type of problem.
Also how are you launching dev mode? Via IDE, via Maven, etc?